# How to batch combine 2 photos into 1 in python

Tags: merge, python-imaging-library, photos

I'm trying to find a way to batch combine multiple pairs of images into a single image horizontally. I have a folder of hundreds of photos (img01, img02,etc) and I'm trying to merge pairs of these:

- img1 + img2 --> img1_2
- img 519 + img 520 --> img519_520

The images are 3 x 4 inches and I want to combine them into pairs of horizontal 6 x 4 inch images.

I have found a way to do this for 2 specific photos but I don't know how to loop the code for all the photos in my image folder and save this as a 6x4 photo.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
images_list = ['img52.JPG', 'img53.JPG']
imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in images_list ]
min_img_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
img_merge = np.hstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_img_shape,Image.ANTIALIAS) ) for i in imgs )
img_merge = Image.fromarray( img_merge)
img_merge.save( 'Merged image.jpg' )
```

I am using a Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4 and python Python 3.6.4.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Source of the above code: https://kanoki.org/2017/07/12/merge-images-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

Update (as of 12 April 2018):

If your images have a name as "img01.JPG", "img42.JPG", this code should work :
you generate all the names and put them in a list. For each pair of images your algorithm converts them into one image and the name of the images created change for every pair.

You must have an even number of images and the images need to be of the same dimension. Thanks a lot to @C. Tim for the helpful response.

```
# Note: I run the program in terminal after I change directory to my folder.

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
images_list = []
for i in range(1,78): #insert last number of photo
    images_list.append('img'+str(i)+'.JPG')
count = 1;

directory = "path of photos to resize"  #change to directory where your photos are
ext = ".jpg"
new_file_name = "vimage-"
new_directory = "path to save in" # change to path of new directory where you want your photos to be saved


for j in range(0,len(images_list),2):
    name = new_file_name + str(j) + ext
    two_images_list = [images_list[j],images_list[j+1]]
    imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in two_images_list ]
    min_img_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
    imgs_comb = np.hstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_img_shape) ) for i in imgs ) )
    imgs_comb = Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
    imgs_comb.save(new_directory+'/'+name )
    count +=1
```

Comment: Hi Tim,

Thanks a lot for replying! I'm having trouble getting the code to work, starting from the "for i in range(10,#last image number+1)" line. It returns an invalid syntax error. Any thoughts? :D

Comment: Yes ! You have to replace the " # last image number" by the real last image number of your image file

Answer (score 0):

Update (as of 12 April 2018):

The following should work for a folder with an even number of photos, where the photos are named: img1.jpg, img2.jpg, etc. The script will take a pair of photos (e.g. img1.jpg and img2.jpg) and combine them.

```
#Note: I run the program in terminal after I change directory to my folder.

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
images_list = []
for i in range(1,78): #insert last number of photo + 1 (in this case, I have 77 photos)
  images_list.append('img'+str(i)+'.JPG')
count = 1;

directory = "path of directory"  #change to directory where your photos are
ext = ".jpg"
new_file_name = "vimage-" #change to what you would like to name your photos
new_directory = "path of directory" # change to path of new directory where you want your photos to be saved


for j in range(0,len(images_list),2):
  name = new_file_name + str(j) + ext
  two_images_list = [images_list[j],images_list[j+1]]
  imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in two_images_list ]
  min_img_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
  imgs_comb = np.hstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_img_shape) ) for i in imgs ) )
  imgs_comb = Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
  imgs_comb.save(new_directory+'/'+name )
  count +=1
```

Thanks a lot to @C. Tim for the helpful response!