# How to run batch combine 2 images into 1 from a folder?

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

Im trying to combine 2 sequence of images into 1 image vertically, and run a loop to all the other images in the folder (contain >200). Eg, img1+img2, img3+img4, img5+img6,....img49+img50..

I refer to the old discussion that discussed the same: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/49715441/16427116**. However, i've encountered error as below (the image exist in the folder);

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0UA33OS9Bos1_1.jpg'**

Below is the code that i run:

```
images_list = []

for i in range(1,50):
    images_list.append('0UA33OS9Bos1_'+str(i)+'.jpg')
count = 1;

directory = "C:/Users/seren/Desktop/ResizeImages"
ext = ".jpg"
new_file_name = "vBos"
new_directory = "C:/Users/seren/Desktop/vcombine"

for j in range(0,len(images_list),2):
  name = new_file_name + str(j) + ext
  two_images_list = [images_list[j],images_list[j+1]]
  imgs = [Image.open(i) for i in two_images_list]
  min_img_shape = sorted([(np.sum(i.size),i.size)for i in imgs])[0][1]
  imgs_comb = np.vstack((np.asarray(i.resize(min_img_shape))for i in imgs))
  imgs_comb = Image.fromarray(imgs_comb)
  imgs_comb.save(new_directory+'/'+name )
  count +=1
```

Can anyone advice me what is wrong here?

Comment: From which folder do you run it?

Comment: The images are in a folder in my desktop. In trying on 50 images first. Do i need to set my dir to the folder first? (im obviously kind of new to this)

Comment: i got it! the code runs successfully and i got all the images combined by 2. I run my notebook on the directory/folder. Although i got results that i wanted, it does shows a warning: "<ipython-input-7-4db3505d6b65>:6: FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future"

Comment: You can make a "sequence" from the generator `(np.asarray(i.resize(min_img_shape))for i in imgs)` by putting `[*` `]` around it.